# For Ubuntu Virtual Machine, how to 'Load AppArmor profiles managed internally by snapd' so VM will boot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, boot, apparmor

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 'VMWare Workstation 16' Virtual Machine on an Ubuntu 20.04 laptop. When I try boot my VM, I see this output:

```
SMBus Host Controller not enabled!
Assuming drive cache: write through
/dev/sda5: clean 519701/1933312 files, 7505521/7732480 blocks
Failed to start Load AppArmor profiles
Failed to start Load AppArmor profiles managed internally by snapd
```

The VM then crashes and does not boot, immediately after the last message above. The first message is also new.

I don't think that I can access the terminal in the VM before the VM crashes. So not sure how I can fix this?

I have information in the VM that I'd like to access.

Milan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When launching the VM, try pressing shift when the VMWare logo comes to enter the manual setup.
After pressing F2, select 'Advanced Options for Ubuntu' and boot in recovery mode. When offered a list of options about what to do, go onto the root terminal. Enter `sudo apt purge snapd` and add `blacklist i2c-piix4` to the bottom of the file /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

Then resume the boot and both are resolved.